# loop through big javascript multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a big json data (with about 20k+ (2mb+)) that I want to show in my pages

So, I get that data with ajax and parse with JSON.parse in javascript and it become a big multidimensional array. Then, I search for some values with defiantjs (js lib for json) with some filters. Then, I use for loop to show them in tables. But, it always says the page is unresponsive (probably because the big data).

It was some kind of sale report.

So, the question is, is there any way to do that faster and without for loops so that it won't crash every time ? 
Or do I have to use foreach because of different performance ?

**[EDIT]**

---

So, every night, I transfer my sales data of my application to a json (averaging 100+ data per day). Now, I want to make a sales report based on the json data. The admin will set the date range (it could be 1 month or 2 month and etc). And there are so many data each day.

Data sample : (in one month, there are approximately 2k+ data with the same format)

```
{
"nojual": "1-00043",
"tgl": 1452038400,
"pelanggan_id": "guest",
"tgltempo": "0000-00-00",
"pay": "cash",
"sales_id": "",
"sisa": "0",
"po": "V5",
"iduser": "riny",
"modedisc": "P",
"total_qty": "4",
"kas": "o",
"sync": "N",
"last_update": "2016-01-06 12:30:54",
"nofaktur": "19",
"service_charge": "0",
"mode_service_charge": "P",
"pb2": "0",
"detail_pay": "",
"diskon_detail_pay": "0",
"tipe_diskon_detail_pay": "",
"ket_diskon": "",
"subtotal": "120000",
"disc": "0",
"pajak": "10",
"grandtotal": "132000",
"nojd": "89",
"barang_id": "20",
"jlhbrg": "2",
"hrgjual": "15000",
"reture": "0",
"tjddisc": "0",
"expired": "0000-00-00",
"total": "30000",
"tjdiduser": "riny",
"tjdmodedisc": null,
"qty": "0",
"satuan": "",
"gudang_id": "",
"id_option": "",
"sp": "tawar",
"tjdsync": "N",
"tjdlast_update": "2016-01-06 12:30:54",
"waiters": "astuti",
"nama_barang": "ice tea",
"jenis": "Minuman"
 }
```

Comment: I recommend adding paging to your site so that you don't load everything at once.

Comment: you will need to consider lazy loading

Comment: 20K+ of what kinds of things?

Comment: No one will ever look through 20.000 rows of anything, so why on earth are you loading it? It makes no sense. You should only load the rows the user wants or needs to see.

Comment: So you want to show a grid or a chart or some other graphics? Can you be more specific about what you want to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than load everything as one large list, I strongly recommend you modify your architecture so that it loads data into pieces. Whether each chunk has five rows or a hundred rows is up to you, but it will certainly make your page much more responsive as well as reduce load and render times.

You can easily achieve this by adding `prev` and `next` links, as well as some page number links, such as `1, 2, ..., 5` to help the user jump to a particular section. If you're looking to reduce page requests, add `Javascript` listeners on your pager links so that they load the rows using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) rather than a full traditional page load.

Or, if you're looking to minimize clicks, you can add `Javascript` listeners on scroll and from there use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) to request the additional rows. This is typically referred to as `infinite scrolling`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to show as a grid with paging or infinite scrolling you can consider https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php this is very good when it comes to huge data.

I hope this can help you.